# (A question regarding:) the graph associated with an open cover of a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Let $X$ denote a topological space and suppose that $\mathcal{O}$ is an open cover of $X$. Assume $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{O}.$ (Thanks Niels!) Now make $\mathcal{O}$ into an (undirected) graph as follows:

- Vertexes: elements of $\mathcal{O}$.
- Edges: we draw an arc between two vertexes iff they have a non-empty intersection when viewed as subsets of $X$.

> **Question.** Is it true that if $X$ is connected (as a topological space), then $\mathcal{O}$ is connected (as a graph)?

The case where the open cover $\mathcal{O}$ has only two elements is easy, but the general case where $\mathcal{O}$ is allowed to have arbitrary cardinality is harder.

Comment: Do you allow for infinite paths?

Comment: @Stefan, no, since I'm not sure what that would mean. Do you have an idea for a definition?

Comment: I think you need to assume that $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{O}$.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen, good point! This makes me wonder whether certain separation axioms may be needed.

Comment: @goblin Turns out I couldn't think of a definition that works in this setting. And Niels / David gave a reason for this... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be true.
Note that if $K \subset \mathcal{O}$ then $\bigcup K$ is an open subset
of $X$. Also, if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are (the vertex sets of) distinct components
 of $\mathcal{O}$,
then $\bigcup K_1 \cap \bigcup K_2 = \emptyset$. Thus the decomposition
of $\mathcal{O}$ into components induces a decomposition of $X$ into
open sets.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Say $E_0\in\mathcal O$. Let $\mathcal O_0$ denote the set of $E\in\mathcal O$ such that $E$ is connected to $E_0$ by a chain of vertices in that graph. Let $\mathcal O_1=\mathcal O\setminus \mathcal O_0$. Let $V_j$ be the union of the $E\in \mathcal O_j$, $j=0,1$. So the $V_j$ are open and $X=V_0\cup V_1$.

Now if $E\in\mathcal O_0$, $F\in\mathcal O$ and $E\cap F\ne\emptyset$ then the definition of $\mathcal O_0$ shows that $F\in\mathcal O_0$. Which is to say that no element of $\mathcal O_0$ can intersect any element of $\mathcal O_1$. Which says that $V_0\cap V_1=\emptyset$.

Since $X$ is connected and $V_0\ne\emptyset$ this shows that $V_1=\emptyset$ and hence $\mathcal O_1=\emptyset$; so $\mathcal O=\mathcal O_0$, saying the graph is connected.